# TextStream object to copy file

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that connects to Oracle, runs a query, and saves the output to a CSV.  Is there an easy way of make a copy of the file using the existing `TextStream` object?

```
' Execute query
Set objResultSet = objConnect.Execute(strSql)

' Create a filename to save query to 
strTimeStamp = DatePart("yyyy",Date) & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & _
               Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2) & Right("0" & Hour(Now), 2) & _
               Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Second(Now), 2)

strOutputFilename = strTimeStamp & ".csv"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputFilename, True)

' Loop through each row of recordset and output to jobcode download file
objResultSet.MoveFirst
Do While Not objResultSet.EOF
    objOutputFile.WriteLine (objResultSet(0) & "," & objResultSet(1))
    objResultSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Yes, you can copy files with the FSO. Have you made an attempt to do so? Have you read the documentation for the FSO?

Comment: I voted down because this question shows no research effort.  Had you searched for even 10 seconds, you would have found the answer.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I should have stated the question better.  I meant to ask could I use the textstream object to make a copy of itself.  I wound up just using objFSO.CopyFile

Answer (score -1):

You could sort-of copy the file by creating files in both locations and writing the content to both files simultaneously. Other than that you'll have to use the [`Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6973t06a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method. [`TextStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) objects only have methods for manipulating the *content* of a file, not its *location*.